# Is there a way to recreate configuration changes using the Windows Registy

Tags: windows, registry

We have a VM running Windows and a bunch of changes were make to get the Windows system to work.  Changes were name to network, disk config, etc.  Now we need to know what all those changes were because we need to apply them to a different version of Windows10.  Is there a way to recreate them given the registry.

I see a lot about looking at the logs, but nothing about recreating the configuration changes

Comment: To automate procedure use data made by system function "Restore previous versions". List previous copies by command: `VSSADMIN list shadows command`. Make link to previous copy `\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy...\`. Then read registry file. Compare previous and current versions. (Mimikatz use this technique to get  data). If you have turned restoration function off ... probably you should make the same configuration work again.